# urlfetchapp.fetch <url> are not permitted ERROR in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, token, google-sheets-api, urlfetch

I had a Google Apps Script code bound to a Google Spreadsheet that created a PDF file from one of its sheets using the urlfetchapp.fetch(url, options) function. Yesterday, without editing the code, it suddenly stopped working, showing the error "urlfetchapp.fetch  are not permitted".

I checked other spreadsheet bound code I made for other Spreadsheet and it is not working anymore either, same error.

For context, I am using Google Workspace for my company, and dealing with sensitive data. But it was working just fine up until yesterday.

```
function CrearPDFysubirloalDrive(){
  var Ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet= Ss.getSheetByName("Name") 
  var Longitud = Sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = Sheet.getRange(1,1,Longitud,10);
  var docId ="Planning"; 
  var docId1Semana = Sheet.getRange('F5').getValue(); 
  var docIdRevision = Sheet.getRange('C7').getValue();
  var pdfname= docId+ " W"+docId1Semana+"-Rev "+docIdRevision; 

  //This is not important to the question
  var tempst= Sheet.copyTo(Ss).setName(pdfname);
  tempst.insertColumns(1);
  tempst.setRowHeight(1,30)
  tempst.setColumnWidth(1, 20);
  tempst.setColumnWidth(12, 30);
  tempst.deleteColumns(13,tempst.getMaxColumns()-12)
  //tempst.deleteRows(Longitud+2, (tempst.getMaxRows()- (Longitud+2)))
  tempst.getRange("A4:A5").setBackground("white");
  var drawing = tempst.getDrawings(); 
  for (let i=0; i<drawing.length;i++){
  drawing[i].remove();
  }
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

//THIS PART IS GIVING THE ERROR
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{ID}/export?'.replace('{ID}', Ss.getId());
  var exportOptions = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=letter' + // paper size legal / letter / A4
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&top_margin=0.40' + //All four margins must be set!
    '&bottom_margin=0.00' + //All four margins must be set!
    '&left_margin=0.40' + //All four margins must be set!
    '&right_margin=0.40' + //All four margins must be set!
    '&gridlines=false' + //true/false
    '&gid=' + tempst.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
  
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions, {
    headers: {
                               Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
    }
  }).getBlob().setName(tempst.getName()+".pdf");

  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);  

  
  var FolderDestino= DriveApp.getFolderById(<FOLDERID>); 
  FolderDestino.createFile(blob.setName(pdfname))
```

I am not an expert at coding by any means, but I suspect it is related to the Oauth token. Either that or the function has been deprecated.

EXACT ERROR CODE:
***Exception: UrlFetch calls to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*******/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=letter&portrait=true&fitw=true&source=labnol&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&fzr=false&top_margin=0.40&bottom_margin=0.00&left_margin=0.40&right_margin=0.40&gridlines=false&gid=2141838874 are not permitted.***

Any help?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

### It seems like there is a bug

The [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/193677240) has already been filed on Google's Issue Tracker. I recommend you to "star" it to increase visibility.